# Issue with placemark 'auto' shading in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a KML file with a list of placemarks that have custom icons, colors, and sizes.  When I display the file in the Google Earth browser plugin, I see that icons that are situated below other icons are shaded.  This makes the color of the icon different from what I have in the `<color>` tag.  How do I disable the shading so that I always see the true color of the icon?

Comment: could you post a link to a screen grab that shows the issue?

Comment: ah - I guess this - https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/earth/DTl6yGLvPvw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in the current version of the Api. You can control the icons color, animation, etc - but the clustering behavior and how it renders the icons is not exposed unfortunately.