# Stop dimming / color change of overlapping placemarks on Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm using Google Earth to display point data as placemarks. The data is on a color-coded scale, and so it's pretty important that they keep their colors (which are set via a series of differently colored icons)

However, Google Earth seems to have a 'feature' whereby it dims some placemarks if they overlap. I can find no reference to this feature, nor any way to avoid it, turn it off, using KML or otherwise.

The question was originally asked here:
https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/earth/DTl6yGLvPvw
Where there are also screenshots of the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748190/kml-how-to-turn-off-icon-shading-for-clusters-of-icons-in-google-earth-browser